# Копирование таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, возникла проблемка, делаю запись на мероприятие, записаться могут только зарегистрированные пользователи, при нажатии на кнопку хочу что бы их данные из одной таблицы копировались в другую, таблицы полностью идентичны, название таблицы зарегистрированных пользователей users а тех кто подаёт заявку uchastniki, в PHP слаб, попробовал написать сам код:

```
<?php
include_once ("bd.php");

$login = $_POST['login'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$query1 = ("SELECT * FROM uchastniki");
$sql = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    echo "Вы уже зарегестрировались";
}
else {
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM uchastniki WHERE id='$id'");
    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 17) {
        echo "Необходимое количество участников набрано";
    }
    else {
        $query = ("INSERT INTO users SELECT * FROM uchastniki");
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрировались";
    }
}
?>
```

Вот что сделал, в итоге он мне каждый раз выдаёт что я успешно зарегистрировался, но данные не копирует, а и главное, хочу сделать чтобы записей в таблице uchastniki было не больше 16. Был бы очень благодарен если написали бы сразу готовый код, я даже готов заплатить уже, меня эта тема выносит уже 3-ое суток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый шедевр!

> $query1 = ("SELECT * FROM
> uchastniki"); $sql =
> mysql_query($query1) or
> die(mysql_error()); if
> (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) { echo "Вы
> уже зарегестрировались";

А зачем тебе логин и пароль?

> $query = ("SELECT * FROM uchastniki
> WHERE id='$id'"); $sql =
> mysql_query($query) or
> die(mysql_error()); if
> (mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 17) { echo
> "Необходимое количесвто участников
> набрано"; }

т.е. при выборе одного участника, ты проверяешь не заполнена ли таблица 16ю записями???

> $query = ("INSERT INTO users SELECT *
> FROM uchastniki"); $result =
> mysql_query($query) or
> die(mysql_error());; echo "Вы успешно
> зарегистрировались";

Тебе нужно постоянно копировать одну таблицу в другую, либо одну запись добавлять в другую таблицу?

Напиши конкретнее!

Comment: В общем мнне нужно что бы когда человек нажимал на кнопку его данные копировались из одной таблицы во вторую, каждый раз после завершения мероприятия таблицу  uchastniki буду пересоздавать постоянно, как бы с нуля ставить, и главное что бы записаться могли не более 16 человек

Comment: И прошу пожалуйста, можно без всяких подколов, я уточнил в своём вопросе то что я в php слаб, и спрашивать "что это?" "для чего это?" думаю как то не этично